# Associate "chrome-extension://" to Chrome browser?

Tags: terminal, applications, bash, google-chrome, ssh

I have installed the [Chrome SSH client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) in my Chrome browser.

How can I make the application association for "chrome-extension://" to the Chrome browser?

I would like to execute this command in Terminal to run application.

```
open chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html
```

Here is my current workaround:

```
SSH_APP=chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome $SSH_APP
```

Comment: Well, you can always hold **command** and double click a link in Terminal, and it should open. When attempting your link (with the double click method), I got a "There is no application set to open the URL chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html" error, which leads me to believe that apps outside of Chrome don't recognize the `chrome-extension` URL scheme.

Comment: I added a solution similar to yours, (but with a lot less typing) to my original answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, as the problem is not within Terminal, but rather in Chrome.app's URL scheme. Chrome does not outwardly expose the `chrome://` and `chrome-extension://` URL schemes, handling them internally (when you access `chrome://history`, `chrome://settings`, etc.).

For example, `open chrome://` does not work in Terminal:

> The file /Users/user/chrome: does not exist.

Yet, typing `open twitter://` in Terminal causes the Mac Twitter app to open on my machine.

---

**However**, you can use a bash alias to achieve a similar effect, with an even easier shortcut:

```
alias chrome_ssh="chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
```

Add the above to your `~/.bash_profile`.